# Mongoose model queries hang in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database file where I set up my schemas/models for mongo and export them. Whenever I reference the models for queries in other files, then run the file in node, it hangs. I get my data back but I have to manually close node. I have tried other solutions like `mongoose.disconnect()` at the end of my database file but that breaks my query.

database.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  stuff: {}
})

const Example = mongoose.model('Example', exampleSchema)

module.exports = {
  Example
}
```

function.js

```
const { Example } = require('../database')

const doSomething = async (name) => {
  const data = await Example.find({ name: name })
}

doSomething('jwhunt19')
```

Comment: if your question is not solved leave a comment, otherwise please accept it, so both of us gain more reputation and other users can see that this answer solved your problem. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

use this url `mongodb://localhost:27017/test` for database connection

```
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
       { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

27017 is your port number for databse coonection, if you want ,you can change it to another number

Answer (score 0):

jsut try like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const connection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    stuff: {}
  })
const doSomething = async (name) => {
  const data = await Example.find({ name: name })
}

doSomething('jwhunt19')

const Example  = connection.model('User', exampleSchema);

module.exports = connection;
```

function.js

```
const connection = require("./database");
const Example  = connection.models.Example  ;
```

Comment: I don't believe this would work for my case, I need the doSomething function to be outside of the database file, whereas you have it inside the database file. I tried exporting the models on connection and it said connection.models is not a function